# Hysteresis and scaling range

Tags: adc, mathematics, filter

[Here](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/93117/54202) I asked about how to add an hysteresis on ADC readings. The answer received was very good and it worked out of the box.

Still I'm having troubles trying to generalize the `resample` function in order to map the input values to a different range of output values, where the lower rail is **not** zero.

If the lower rail was zero, it would be enough to change the shifts with a multiplication/division for `1024 / max`. But I cannot understand how to handle the lower rail when `min > 0`.

My attempt:

```
int Menu::resample(int adc, int *value, byte min, byte max)
{    
    // sanity checks omitted: min < max and max < 128

    double m = 1015.0 / (max - min); // 1015 = 1023 - 8 (1 LSB of low-res output)
                                     // otherwise it reaches 126 even if max = 127
    int q = min << 3;

    int lowerTest = (q + *value * m) - ADC_HYSTERESIS;
    int higherTest = (q + (*value + 1) * m) + ADC_HYSTERESIS;

    int lowerOutput = min + (adc + ADC_HYSTERESIS) / m;
    int higherOutput = min + (adc - ADC_HYSTERESIS) / m;

    if (adc < lowerTest) *value = lowerOutput;
    else if (adc >= higherTest) *value = higherOutput;

    if (*value > max) *value = max;
    if (*value < min) *value = min;
    return *value;
}
```

There is something wrong in my math, since the comparison always falls under the first `if` (i.e. `*value = lowerOutput`).

May you help me to fix this code so I can have an hysteresis on any scaled output?

**Note**: instead of using a static variable for value as in the answer, I use a `struct`:

```
slider.value = resample(adc, &slider.lastValue, slider.min, slider.max);
```

where:

```
typedef struct
{
    int value;
    int lastValue;
    int min;
    int max;
} slider_t;

slider_t slider;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a couple of comments about this first attempt.

There is no point in storing in `slider_t` both `lastValue` and `value`.
The way this is used, both fields are always updated with the same
value: `lastValue` is updated by pointer inside `resample()`, while
`value` is updated by assigning it the value returned by `resample()`. I
would suggest removing the field `lastValue` and either:

1. providing `value` by value (rather than by pointer) to `resample()`,
   or
2. providing a reference to a `slider_t` as the only parameter.

The first approach is better if you want to avoid `resample()` and
`slider_t` being tightly coupled.

Next, there is a mix between `int` and `byte` types. If you want to save
memory, and improve consistency, I would use `byte` for all low-res
values living in the output domain of `resample()`. Actually, I would
use `uint8_t`, which is the same, only more standard.

Then, there are a few things I do not understand in this code:

- Why `1015`? It seems to me this number should be dependent on the
  width of output range.
- Why `min << 3`? Again, this is a division by 8, while the proper
  factor should be probably be output-range dependent.

Now, for the solution, I would try this approach:

- Compute the minimum and maximum possible output values consistent with
  the provided input, accounting for the hysteresis.
- Constrain the output to remain within this bracket.

In code:

```cpp
uint8_t Menu::resample(int adc, uint8_t value, uint8_t min, uint8_t max)
{
    value = constrain(value, min, max);  // just in case...
    uint8_t lower = map(adc - ADC_HYSTERESIS, 0, 1024, min, max+1);
    uint8_t upper = map(adc + ADC_HYSTERESIS, 0, 1024, min, max+1);
    return constrain(value, lower, upper);
}
```

Some points worth noticing:

1. I do not know whether this was originally intended, but the Arduino
   function `map(x, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max)` does a poor job
   at mapping the interval [`in_min`, `in_max`] to [`out_min`,
   `out_max`]. It does, however, do a good job at mapping [`in_min`,
   `in_max`) to [`out_min`, `out_max`) (mind the semi-open intervals).
   This is why the four last parameters of the call to `map()` are (0,
   1024, min, max+1), rather than (0, 1023, min, max).
2. The first call to `constrain()` can be removed if the caller bears
   the responsibility of guaranteeing this precondition.
3. If the precondition is valid (or, like here, enforced), it will also
   hold for the returned value, provided `adc` is within [0, 1024).

This method would be called like this:

```cpp
slider.value = resample(adc, slider.value, slider.min, slider.max);
```

Comment: It's unbelievable how a quite complex task can be solved with few lines of code. I'm impressed. Thank you!